# How to store a secret or a private key securely in Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, security, silverlight-4.0

This is a Silverlight 4 specific question. Silverlight 5 Beta already addresses this concern by providing ProtectedData and DPAPI access.

This is not a question relating to how to store a users password, for that hashing is the answer.

How do I store a secret in the client, in a way which will not be vulnerable to a memory dump or reflection/decompilation?

Or do you think SSL is secure enough and no further encryption of data is necessary? An example would be a user submitting a password change request, in which old and new password must be sent to the server for the operation. Assume that the data on the server is secure in memory and at rest.

Comment: you can't ever really store something secure in a client... per definition anything the client itself needs to use means that it can be gotten to that information... if you just need to communicate sensitive data use SSL thus securing the transport, the main security burden is on the server side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't ever safe to store your private key on the client... That's why it's private :)

SSL is 128-bit (minimum) and is much more than adequate for any of your needs. So long as you force SSL. If you're really concerned, up your SSL bitrate and there you go.

"256 bits is roughly equal to the number of atoms in the universe."

"Brute force techniques are considered impractical because modern encryption algorithms are 128 to 256 bits long."

- According to :
  http://www.zdnet.com/blog/ou/is-encryption-really-crackable/204

If the client has the program, there is always a chance to get your stored key if you embed it in.

Comment: Using proper authentication and authorization, as well as Xap signing and a this.Host.Source check on app start up- I think it's acceptable to handle encryption and decryption on the server side for at-rest data security. The key on the server side should be stored using DPAPI, not hard-coded. You can use SQL's built-in mechanisms to do transparent data encryption (TDE), but that doesn't protect against a DB admin from seeing people's PII.